# Live CD ubuntu 13.10 is not working with hp printer 1020 plus

Tags: installation, printing

I am new to Linux . we have new requirement where in I have to connect HP 1020 plus printer with Ubuntu live cd . I have tried a lot but unable to do . when we are installing new hplib from site I is working but in live cd we are unable to do that so please give solution .

Answer (score 1):

Live CD is not containin extracted driver packages.You need to visit HP's site and download suitable driver for your printer.and then install that driver to Live Cd.and try connect again.by the way go to settings-printers.check if your printer is connected or not